# Parameter Info Tooltip using Roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, roslyn

I would like to develop my own tooltip for Parameter Info (which pops up as soon as you start entering parameters in a function call).

[image]

I would like to implement it using Roslyn, but I don't know where to start. Can anyone provide me a small example to get me started?

Comment: Roslyn is a compiler, intellisense is part of the IDE.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: No; Roslyn also includes the IDE language services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should preface this by pointing out that extending Visual Studio is not a particularly easy, fun or straightforward endeavor.

I believe the MSDN article [Walkthrough: Displaying Signature Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee334194.aspx) should get you off to a good start.

> The Signature Help source is based on signatures that implement `ISignature`, each of which contains parameters that implement `IParameter`.

So first we have to create a parameter that inherits from [IParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.iparameter.aspx).

Next we have to create a signature that inherits from [ISignature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.isignature.aspx). The key here is to implement a `CurrentParameterChanged` event that is fired as the user types commas, changing with parameter's definition should be shown.

This is accomplished by creating the event and firing it as follows:

```
public event EventHandler<CurrentParameterChangedEventArgs> CurrentParameterChanged;

public IParameter CurrentParameter
{
    get { return m_currentParameter; }
    internal set
    {
        if (m_currentParameter != value)
        {
            IParameter prevCurrentParameter = m_currentParameter;
            m_currentParameter = value;
            this.RaiseCurrentParameterChanged(prevCurrentParameter, m_currentParameter);
        }
    }
}

private void RaiseCurrentParameterChanged(IParameter prevCurrentParameter, IParameter newCurrentParameter)
{
    EventHandler<CurrentParameterChangedEventArgs> tempHandler = this.CurrentParameterChanged;
    if (tempHandler != null)
    {
        tempHandler(this, new CurrentParameterChangedEventArgs(prevCurrentParameter, newCurrentParameter));
    }
}
```

They computer the current parameter based on the number of commas in the string. The `ComputeCurrentParameter()` method is a little too long to post here, however.

Next you have to implement [`ISignatureHelpSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.isignaturehelpsource.aspx). This interface provides signature help information for Intellisense.

The method `ISignatureHelpSource.AugmentSignatureHelpSession()` is where the list of parameter information is created and where you'll be adding your custom parameter information. The MSDN provided example uses pre-written strings here. In reality, you'd probably want to calculate these things on the fly, perhaps with Roslyn, depending on your goals.

Finally, you must export an [`ISignatureHelpSourceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.isignaturehelpsourceprovider.aspx) via [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx). This allows Visual Studio to consume your `ISignatureHelpSource`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!! So to my understanding,  in order to do this Roslyn alone is not enough?  Also,  I've seen this example before and I noticed there is nothing related to custom drawing the tooltip. Is that a possibility?  Thanks Josh!!

Comment: Well you would likely use Roslyn to figure out what values to place within the signature help. But yes, you still need to interface and integrate with Visual Studio in order to show your signature help tips.

Comment: When you say custom drawing, do you mean changing the colors, having custom icons and so on? If so, then you'd probably need to create your own mechanism for displaying and triggering that item. It's possible, but probably somewhat difficult.